# Preload second page while viewing the current page

Tags: jquery, ajax

Let's say my website has 5 pages of content.  Is it possible to preload the next two pages while visitor is viewing the first page.  So that when they click the link to 2nd or 3rd page, it will appear immediately.

Comment: Use invisible elements as containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can have some invisble containers like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="page">
  <a href="page2.html" id="page2-link">Go second page</a>
</div>
<div id="page2">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#page2 { display:none }
```

**Javascript**

Then when at the javascript preload the second page after it has been loaded and put it on the invisble container:

```
$().ready(function(){
  $('#page2').load('page2.html #page');
});
```

And when the link is clicked just show the hidden container with selected page and remove the other, or just hide it to not load again when user wants to return or something.

```
$().ready(function(){
  $('#page2-link').on('click',function(){
       $('#page').html( $('#page').html() ); //this will replace html content
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you explain more on changing the hidden container to visible part?  Sorry I am still a beginner at jQuery

Comment: I just added how to interchange content

Comment: Sorry was onto other part of my project.  Will try this now and get back to you shortly.

Comment: I didn't realize that I have actually implemented this unintentionally while dealing with another matter.  So I will mark this as working.  Thanks for your help!